# What does the syntax ?. mean in this Ruby example?

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby and found this code sample in some documentation:

```
require 'find'

  total_size = 0

  Find.find(ENV["HOME"]) do |path|
    if FileTest.directory?(path)
      if File.basename(path)[0] == ?.
        Find.prune       # Don't look any further into this directory.
      else
        next
      end
    else
      total_size += FileTest.size(path)
    end
  end
```

The purpose is to sum up the file sizes of all files in a tree, excluding directories that start with a dot. The line `if File.basename(path)[0] == ?.` is obviously performing the directory name test. I would have written it like this:

```
if File.basename(path)[0] == "."
```

What does `?.` do? (Could be a typo, I suppose.) I have not seen this syntax described elsewhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`?.` returns the ASCII value of the dot. You can put pretty much any char after the question mark to get its ASCII value, like `?a` or `?3` or `?\\`, etc. The reason they are not comparing it to the string `"."` is that when you index into a string, you get the ASCII value of the char at that index rather than the char itself. To get the char at a certain index you can use `[0, 1]` as the index. So the options are:

```
if File.basename(path)[0] == ?.
```

Or:

```
if File.basename(path)[0, 1] == "."
```

Or even:

```
if File.basename(path)[0].chr == "."
```

Comment: Thank you! I now recall reading about that operator. This Perl programmer has a lot to unlearn.

Answer (score 2):

It is a shorthand for the ASCII code point of the "." character. See the documentation on [numeric literals](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#numeric) in the Ruby syntax.

```
>> ?.
=> 46
>> ?a
=> 97
```

Comment: Note that this behavior changed in Ruby 1.9. In Ruby 1.9, `?a` returns the string `"a"`, which is consistent with indexing a string, which also returns a string instead of a number.

Answer (score 1):

It means to return the character code of the next character. In Ruby, saying string[0] gives you a character code, so it's like saying is the first character a ".".

Interestingly, it means that expressions like `???!?!??` are perfectly legal in Ruby.

Take a look [here](http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/tut_stdtypes.html).

Comment: I have yet to find that part of Ruby that is "easy to learn".

Comment: I don't know if it's incredibly easy to learn, but it does have a lot of really nice aspects to its syntax. I'm primarily a JavaScript programmer and there are many times I wish I had Ruby's block syntax or its "everything returns a value" orthogonality.

Comment: that's a totally random use of the word orthogonality.